# Unable to connect to the remote server occurs after trying to build NSB v4

Tags: nservicebus3

I started getting this error with new projects running v3 after trying to build v4 while trying to figure out why I couldn't get v3 to work in an MVC4 environment. John Simons pointed out what I was missing so I was able to get the MVC4 built with v3. However, the problem is unrelated to the MVC project, since the error occurs even when I only start the "Asa_Server" Class Library portion of the solution.

The v4 build (I'm assuming) is the develop branch of the github repo. The build errored out, saying that I needed to upgrade raven (which I did not do). I'm wondering if that has anything to do with it?

Inner exception:

```
No connection could be made
because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:8080
```

Stack Trace

```
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
at Raven.Client.Connection.HttpJsonRequest.ReadStringInternal(Func`1 getResponse) in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable\Raven.Client.Lightweight\Connection\HttpJsonRequest.cs:line 288
at Raven.Client.Connection.HttpJsonRequest.ReadResponseString() in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable\Raven.Client.Lightweight\Connection\HttpJsonRequest.cs:line 207
at Raven.Client.Connection.HttpJsonRequest.ExecuteRequest() in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable\Raven.Client.Lightweight\Connection\HttpJsonRequest.cs:line 151
at Raven.Client.Connection.ServerClient.DirectPutIndex(String name, String operationUrl, Boolean overwrite, IndexDefinition definition) in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable\Raven.Client.Lightweight\Connection\ServerClient.cs:line 709
at Raven.Client.Connection.ServerClient.<>c__DisplayClass3b.<PutIndex>b__3a(String operationUrl) in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable\Raven.Client.Lightweight\Connection\ServerClient.cs:line 687
at Raven.Client.Connection.ServerClient.TryOperation[T](Func`2 operation, String operationUrl, Boolean avoidThrowing, T& result) in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable\Raven.Client.Lightweight\Connection\ServerClient.cs:line 231
at Raven.Client.Connection.ServerClient.ExecuteWithReplication[T](String method, Func`2 operation) in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable\Raven.Client.Lightweight\Connection\ServerClient.cs:line 195
at Raven.Client.Connection.ServerClient.PutIndex(String name, IndexDefinition definition, Boolean overwrite) in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable\Raven.Client.Lightweight\Connection\ServerClient.cs:line 687
at Raven.Client.Connection.ServerClient.PutIndex[TDocument,TReduceResult](String name, IndexDefinitionBuilder`2 indexDef, Boolean overwrite) in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable\Raven.Client.Lightweight\Connection\ServerClient.cs:line 748
at NServiceBus.Timeout.Hosting.Windows.Persistence.RavenTimeoutPersistence..ctor(IDocumentStore store) in c:\BuildAgent\work\nsb.master_6\src\timeout\NServiceBus.Timeout.Hosting.Windows\Persistence\RavenTimeoutPersistence.cs:line 21
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the service was stopped. It seems the build for v4 may have caused ravendb to hang or something. After I started raven again, the error message went away.